# How to properly disconnect from a BLE app on a Marshmallow device?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am recently working on a BLE App to control LED lights.I am able to connect and send strings to the BLE device from android 7.1.1 (Nougat). I am also able to connect and disconnect multiple times but when I am disconnecting from a device running Android 6 (marshmallow) the BLE device is either going to sleep or it is not disconnecting properly.
I am running the following code to disconnect:-

```
private void Disconnect() {
    Toast.makeText(mBTLE_Service, "Service Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mBTLE_Service.disconnect();
    mBTLE_Service.close();

    finish();
}
```

And I am running the following code from the service to disconnect and close.

```
/**
 * Disconnects an existing connection or cancel a pending connection. The disconnection result
 * is reported asynchronously through the
 * {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
 * callback.
 */
public void disconnect() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }

    mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
}

/**
 * After using a given BLE device, the app must call this method to ensure resources are
 * released properly.
 */
public void close() {

    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        return;
    }

    mBluetoothGatt.close();
    mBluetoothGatt = null;
}
```

Also, my app does not run on any device below Android 5 and on Android 5 I am able to connect but not able to send any data to the BLE device.I am using the BM70_BLE device.
What changes do I need to make to my app so that I can provide support for all the devices above Android 4.4? Like BLE Scanner is able to both connect and send data to devices above Android 4.4.Link for BLE Scanner https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macdom.ble.blescanner&hl=en

Any help or support is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @mag_zbc.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not run"? The app crashes or you just cannot install on the devices? Please check if your code contains BluetoothLeScanner (available on Android 5+ only)

Comment: @reTs The app crashes.